# Reading audio from the same computer where Arduino gets power supply

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino, and I want to read from a 3.5 mm jack cable.

I powered Arduino with an USB plug to the computer. I created a voltage divider, joined the computer's output jack's one of the pin, and took the other to the analog input of the Arduino.

But when I tested it, the voltage of the resistor connected to the ground was 0V. The problem turned out to be because of the audio and the USB plug were connected to the same computer. (If I power Arduino from batteries, it works fine) "Funny" thing is that if I power these from different computers, it doesn't work.

But I need to plug these to the same computer, so is there any (easy) electronics to read the audio properly?

Comment: Please explain the audio jack part a bit more carefully. Which of the Jack Tip Ring Sleeve are connected, and to where? Ideally, draw us a circuit diagram including the PC ground and USB cable, and it might be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: Could you suggest a program to draw the diagram?

Comment: This site has a nice link to a Circuit Lab site - just edit your question and click the Insert Circuit Diagram button on the toolbar.  For yourself, you could draw it on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to introduce a difference between grounds.  Instead, use capacitive coupling and bias the ATmega's end of the capacitor to half the ADC reference using moderate value resistors.  (Most, but not all soundcards already have a cap, but use your own.)

Bear in mind the ATmega328p is not a particularly high fidelity choice for audio.  For better results you probably want something with a 16 but audio-spec Sigma-Delta ADC.

Or, with a faster part having its own USB interface you can present as a USB sound card or custom digital audio sink.